# PyQt5: What does the param "Union" mean in a method signature?

Tags: python, pyqt5, typing, qtextedit

For example:

```
self.content_text = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
self.content_text.setTextColor( ? )
```

The params are:

```
(self, Union, QColor=None, Qt_GlobalColor=None, QGradient=None)
```

What is `Union`? Which value should I type in?

Answer (score 0):

Method setTextColor has following prototype (from QTextEdit.py):

```
def setTextColor(self, Union, QColor=None, Qt_GlobalColor=None, QGradient=None):
    """ setTextColor(self, Union[QColor, Qt.GlobalColor, QGradient]) """
    pass
```

Union here is [typing.Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union), that used for type hints. Union[QColor, Qt.GlobalColor, QGradient] means "parameter with type QColor or Qt.GlobalColor or QGradient". For some reason it appears in params list too while docstring `setTextColor(self, Union[QColor, Qt.GlobalColor, QGradient])` is correct. In your program use this method like

```
self.content_text.setTextColor(QtGui.QColor(124, 124, 134))
```

Comment: Thanks. So,with Union, I can put any param(QColor, Qt_GlobalColor, QGradient) anywhere(whichever goes first) without typing 'QColor='